# Zipping all files and subdirectories inside a folder using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window, zip, winrar

I wrote the below script to zip all the files and sub directories inside a folder. But I am only getting the sub directories zipped. What am I doing wrong here? Please advice.

```
FOR /D %%i IN ("*") DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a ../../../apps-1.0.2.zip "%%~fi\"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try for this example and tell me the results :

> -R Switch : for recurring subfolders
>
> -AF`<Type>` Switch  : specify the archive format
>
> -EP1 Switch : to exclude the names of the basic folder
>
> -DH Switch: open shared files : Can process files opened by other applications.
>   This switch is useful if an application allows access the file read, but if all access is prohibited, the file open always fail.

```
@echo off
Set Winrar=%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe
Set MyFolder=%USERPROFILE%\Favorites
Set ArchiveName=apps-1.0.2.zip
"%Winrar%" a -r -afzip -ep1 -dh "%ArchiveName%" "%MyFolder%"
pause
```

**Edit on 29/06/2016 @13:30**

For others switchs and commands you can execute this batch to open the help file of Winrar :

```
@echo off
Set WinrarHelp=%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.chm
Start "" "%WinrarHelp%"
```

Comment: Thanks mate! You to the rescue again :) btw where do you find those parameters?

Comment: @mayooran Check my last edit to find others switchs and commands !