# How to unzip several *.zip archive files into separate folders?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, unzip, winrar

I searched with Google but I didn't find something for Windows.

How can I extract several files into several folders?

For example: `a.zip`, `b.zip` and `c.zip` into the folders `a`, `b` and `c`.

I am looking for a command prompt command or a batch file solution.

Thanks

Comment: probably you haven't seen [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat)

Comment: Take a look at this **[How to extract all zip files in a folder using winrar with the same name as the zip ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064341/how-to-extract-all-zip-files-in-a-folder-using-winrar-with-the-same-name-as-the?answertab=active#tab-top)**

Comment: thanks Hackoo that worked for me

Answer (score 3):

With using *WinRAR* in GUI mode:

1. Start *WinRAR*.
2. Select all the *.zip files.
3. Click on icon **Extract To** in toolbar.
4. Enter destination folder or browse to destination folder.
5. Check the option *Extract archives to subfolders* in group *Miscellaneous*.
6. Click on button **OK**.

In case of you want to know more about those extracting options, click before on button **Help**.

Or use from command line with current directory containing the *.zip files and all archive files which should be also extracted into subfolders of current directory with name of ZIP file as folder name:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -ad -cfg- -ibck *.zip
```

**How to build such a *WinRAR* command line?**

1. Start *WinRAR*.
2. Click in menu **Help** on **Help topics**.
3. Click on tab **Contents** on list item **Command line mode**.
4. Click on list item *Command line syntax*, read this help page and copy the bold line into a text editor or into a command prompt window.
5. Click on tab **Contents** on list item **Commands**.
6. Click on list item *Alphabetic commands list* and replace `<command>` in text editor or command prompt window by most suitable command letter for the task.
7. Click on tab **Contents** on list item **Switches**.
8. Click on list item *Alphabetic switches list* and replace `-<switch1> -<switchN>` in text editor or command prompt window by those switches which are useful for the task.
9. Replace the rest of the *WinRAR* command line in text editor or command prompt window by the appropriate file and/or folder names.

The short explanation of the most important switch `-ad` for this task is:

> **-ad**     append archive name to destination path

As it can be seen here, *WinRAR* supports even a wildcard pattern as archive file name for extracting all archives files matching the pattern.

One more method exists with shell integration enabled as by default after installation of *WinRAR*.

1. Select the archive files to extract in file manager (Windows Explorer).
2. Click with secondary (right) mouse button on one of the selected files to open the context menu.
3. Open context submenu **WinRAR** if there is such a submenu because of enabled setting *Cascaded context menus* in *WinRAR* - **Options - Settings - Integration**.
4. Click on context menu item **Extract each archive to separate folder**.